# Counting number of items in an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, items

I keep getting the output of `100` when I do what everyone else online has been posting about:

`int total = sizeof(num)/sizeof(int);`

It doesn't seem to work for me. Here's my code:

```
int main() {
    static int num[100];
    int totalNum = sizeof(num)/sizeof(int);
    return 0;
}

void readNumbers(int* num) {
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/Users/Documents/hello.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("Could not load file");
        exit(0);
    }
    /* Loads numbers into num array */
    int number;
    while(fscanf(fp, "%d", &number) > 0) {
        num[i] = number;
        i++;
    }
}
```

My output is 100 so I'm assuming there isn't anything that is inserted into the num array? And if I print out `sizeof(num)` it gives me a hundred; 4 bytes * 100 = 400.

Here is what is in `hello.txt`:

`14 21 39 48 109 3882`

Comment: `readNumbers()` is never called in the code you've shown. And your format string in `fscanf()` is missing a parenthesis.

Comment: The given code won't even compile. Please post the *exact* code.

Comment: A good question has four parts. 1. What you've done. 2. What output you get from that. 3. What you expected the output to be 4. Why you expected the output to be different.

Comment: BTW, that's the expected behavior. 100 is supposed to be the output.

Comment: I mean. I want to output the number of items in the array which is supposed to be `6`, however, it is giving me 100 instead.

Comment: @user3386109, Thank you so much! That was all I wanted to know. I would give you a thumbs up if I could.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike arrays in other languages (that can grow and shrink, and will tell you how many elements the array currently contains), a C array is just a simple block of memory that has a fixed size. You declared an array that can hold 100 elements, and that's all `sizeof` is going to tell you.

If you want to know how many numbers you've put in the array, then you have to keep track of that in a separate variable. The array itself doesn't contain that information.